# Embedded plot in pyqt5 shows in taskbar but won't display when clicked

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am trying to embed a graph widget in my pyqt5 window. I have created a mainwindow in designer using the graphview widget to promote the pyqtgraph widget. I have then exported the ui file to python code using pyuic5.

When I run the code in my python environment I get I get no errors and the window shows in the taskbar...but won't show properly. When I click the preview in the taskbar it doesn't show up in the full view. See

[image]

taskbar view of the gui shows it fine but when clicked it won't un-minimise

I have tried this with both matplotlib and pyqtgraph and had the exact same issue (window showing in taskbar but not un-minimising when clicked). Is this something with the way I have tried to embed the graph?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For reference all of my other pyqt5 gui windows without promoted widgets work fine, it seems to be only these two with the graphs.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
import icons

class Ui_reportWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, reportWindow):
        reportWindow.setObjectName("reportWindow")
        reportWindow.resize(1057, 663)
        reportWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1057, 663))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/report_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        reportWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        reportWindow.setWindowOpacity(0.0)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(reportWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1041, 111))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.cbRoomNum = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox)
        self.cbRoomNum.setObjectName("cbRoomNum")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.cbRoomNum, 0, 1, 2, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 2, 2, 1)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.groupBox)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.line, 0, 3, 5, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_3, 0, 5, 1, 1)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_4, 0, 7, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_5, 0, 9, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 8, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1, 0, 11, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(41, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem2, 1, 4, 2, 1)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem3, 1, 6, 2, 1)
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem4, 1, 8, 2, 1)
        spacerItem5 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(41, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem5, 1, 10, 2, 1)
        self.pbGenerateReport = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pbGenerateReport.setObjectName("pbGenerateReport")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pbGenerateReport, 1, 11, 2, 1)
        spacerItem6 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem6, 1, 12, 2, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 2, 1)
        self.tbReportNum = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.tbReportNum.setObjectName("tbReportNum")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.tbReportNum, 2, 1, 2, 1)
        spacerItem7 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 23, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem7, 3, 7, 2, 1)
        spacerItem8 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 23, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem8, 3, 9, 2, 1)
        spacerItem9 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 23, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem9, 3, 11, 2, 1)
        self.pbTenHours = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pbTenHours.setObjectName("pbTenHours")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pbTenHours, 3, 5, 2, 1)
        self.tbTotalTime = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.tbTotalTime.setObjectName("tbTotalTime")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.tbTotalTime, 1, 9, 2, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 2, 1)
        self.sbStopTime = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.sbStopTime.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.UpDownArrows)
        self.sbStopTime.setKeyboardTracking(False)
        self.sbStopTime.setMaximumTime(QtCore.QTime(23, 59, 59))
        self.sbStopTime.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.sbStopTime.setCurrentSectionIndex(0)
        self.sbStopTime.setObjectName("sbStopTime")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.sbStopTime, 1, 7, 2, 1)
        self.sbStartTime = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.sbStartTime.setMaximumDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2000, 1, 1), QtCore.QTime(23, 59, 59)))
        self.sbStartTime.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.sbStartTime.setObjectName("sbStartTime")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.sbStartTime, 1, 5, 2, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.reportPlot = PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.reportPlot.setObjectName("reportPlot")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.reportPlot)
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 56)
        self.progressBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.progressBar.setInvertedAppearance(False)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        reportWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(reportWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1057, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuSettings = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuSettings.setObjectName("menuSettings")
        self.menu_Help = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu_Help.setObjectName("menu_Help")
        self.menu_Export = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu_Export.setObjectName("menu_Export")
        reportWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(reportWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        reportWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action_User_Manual = QtWidgets.QAction(reportWindow)
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/userManual_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.action_User_Manual.setIcon(icon1)
        self.action_User_Manual.setObjectName("action_User_Manual")
        self.action_Save = QtWidgets.QAction(reportWindow)
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/save_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.action_Save.setIcon(icon2)
        self.action_Save.setObjectName("action_Save")
        self.action_Return_Home = QtWidgets.QAction(reportWindow)
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/home_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.action_Return_Home.setIcon(icon3)
        self.action_Return_Home.setObjectName("action_Return_Home")
        self.actionExcel_File = QtWidgets.QAction(reportWindow)
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/excelFile_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionExcel_File.setIcon(icon4)
        self.actionExcel_File.setObjectName("actionExcel_File")
        self.actionPDF_File = QtWidgets.QAction(reportWindow)
        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/pdfFile_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionPDF_File.setIcon(icon5)
        self.actionPDF_File.setObjectName("actionPDF_File")
        self.actionLog_In = QtWidgets.QAction(reportWindow)
        icon6 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon6.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/adminOn_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionLog_In.setIcon(icon6)
        self.actionLog_In.setObjectName("actionLog_In")
        self.actionLog_Out = QtWidgets.QAction(reportWindow)
        icon7 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon7.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/adminOff_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionLog_Out.setIcon(icon7)
        self.actionLog_Out.setObjectName("actionLog_Out")
        self.actionCSV_File = QtWidgets.QAction(reportWindow)
        icon8 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon8.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/csvFile_icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionCSV_File.setIcon(icon8)
        self.actionCSV_File.setObjectName("actionCSV_File")
        self.action_Print = QtWidgets.QAction(reportWindow)
        self.action_Print.setObjectName("action_Print")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.action_Print)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.action_Return_Home)
        self.menuSettings.addAction(self.actionLog_In)
        self.menuSettings.addAction(self.actionLog_Out)
        self.menu_Help.addAction(self.action_User_Manual)
        self.menu_Export.addAction(self.actionExcel_File)
        self.menu_Export.addAction(self.actionPDF_File)
        self.menu_Export.addAction(self.actionCSV_File)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_Export.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuSettings.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_Help.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(reportWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(reportWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, reportWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        reportWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("reportWindow", "Report"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("reportWindow", "Set Parameters"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("reportWindow", " Start:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "Report End:"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "Report Length:"))
        self.pbGenerateReport.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "Generate Report"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "Enter Report Number:"))
        self.pbTenHours.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "-24 hours"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "Select Room:"))
        self.sbStopTime.setDisplayFormat(_translate("reportWindow", "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm "))
        self.sbStartTime.setDisplayFormat(_translate("reportWindow", "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm "))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("reportWindow", "&File"))
        self.menuSettings.setTitle(_translate("reportWindow", "&Settings"))
        self.menu_Help.setTitle(_translate("reportWindow", "&Help"))
        self.menu_Export.setTitle(_translate("reportWindow", "&Export"))
        self.action_User_Manual.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "&User Manual"))
        self.action_Save.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "&Save"))
        self.action_Save.setShortcut(_translate("reportWindow", "Ctrl+S"))
        self.action_Return_Home.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "&Return Home"))
        self.action_Return_Home.setShortcut(_translate("reportWindow", "Ctrl+W"))
        self.actionExcel_File.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "&Excel File"))
        self.actionPDF_File.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "&PDF File"))
        self.actionLog_In.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "Log In"))
        self.actionLog_In.setShortcut(_translate("reportWindow", "Ctrl+L"))
        self.actionLog_Out.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "Log Out"))
        self.actionLog_Out.setShortcut(_translate("reportWindow", "Ctrl+O"))
        self.actionCSV_File.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "&CSV File"))
        self.action_Print.setText(_translate("reportWindow", "&Print"))



class chamberReportWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        super(chamberReportWindow,self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        self.ui = Ui_reportWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


    def update_graph(self):
        pass

#this is module testing code can be deleted when incorporated into the main gui
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = chamberReportWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Remove this line: `reportWindow.setWindowOpacity(0.0)`. It makes the window completely transparent.

Comment: Thanks Heike, that works. Some reason only this export from designer added that opacity line.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with PyQt6.

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import uic
#from pnpGUI import Ui_Dialog 
#from PyQt6.uic import loadUi


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

class mainDlg(QMainWindow):
    """Main dialog."""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("C:\Code\PnP_Robot\GUI_interface\GUI_interface\pnpGUI.ui", self)
        self.show()
dlg = mainDlg()
app.exec()
```

now if I change the QmainWindow to QDialog and change the pnpGUI.ui to pnpGUI_Dialog it works. So I think it has something to do with QmainWindow